# Backed up mail?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, idiomatic-language

I'm working on a late *Thank you* email to my co-workers in response to the *Get well soon* card I got in the mail.

> Hi team, I got the **backed up mail** today from the mailbox and saw a very cool looking *Get well soon* card you all have signed. Thank you for your well wishes and sentiments! I very much appreciate the kind gesture!

Is back up here used correctly?  I looked it up and didn't see it used in this type of context, but this is the only phrasal verb that comes to mind to describe a pile of mail in the mailbox that was sent awhile back.

Is there an idiomatic way to describe this?

Comment: `...Thank you for your well wishes...` - **well** is definitely wrong here as it's an adverb. You must use an adjective instead. For instance, `kind`. `I very much appreciate the kind gesture!` - word order is wrong here. It could be ``I appreciate this kind gesture very much!``

Comment: @Anatolii, Thank you for the grammar tips!

Answer (score 1):

Glad you’re feeling better!

It’s not the most natural construction but is one whose general meaning is understandable. For native American English speakers, at least, the phrase **backed up** meaning stopped or overflowing (as opposed to computer files being copied elsewhere) is commonly used to describe a toilet being clogged. If your recent illness may have involved any sort of bowel upset, different phrasing is definitely in order.

Your mail **piled up** because you probably felt too ill to even **check the mail**, that is, to walk to the box and see whether you had any deliveries. You might express that as

> After finally feeling up to checking the mail for the first time in four days, I enjoyed reading the get-well card that everyone signed. Thank you for taking time for your thoughtful gesture.

If you tend to be more private or understated, then

> Now that I’m able to catch up on my mail …

or just

> Catching up with the mail …

Note that the English word mail is a [mass noun or uncountable noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun). This means <s>mails</s> is incorrect. Whether it’s a single letter, parcel, or many pieces of mail, grammatical usage refers to it as a single whole, *e.g.*, “The driver delivered the mail.” The same is true for email, which derives from electronic mail, that may contain notes, letters, memos, and so on. Error on this point (<s>three emails</s>) is widespread, and correcting it may induce non-responses such as “it’s just different” or “don’t be a prescriptivist.”

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: By the way as a non-native, *"Thank you for taking time for your thoughtful gesture,"* is not a construction I had heard before. I would've said, "Thank you for taking the time to make such a thoughtful gesture." I was wondering if you could confirm that your sentence is indeed grammatically correct.

Comment: @Bahram You’re welcome! Yours is a more formal way to express it. In my less formal version, “to make” is implied. For a response to a nice card, less formal is what I’d suggest. People from other cultures sometimes complain that Americans can be too chummy or overly friendly. Connecting your coworkers to their sentiment with a possessive as in “your gesture” is more personal, in contrast to an article, either “the gesture” or “a gesture,” that may come across as distant or detached.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to me, so I won't say it is wrong. It could cause some confusion as "backed-up mail" makes me think of a *digital* backup, perhaps of *email*.

You might also call it a *backlog of mail*. The most natural way to express it seems to me to be "*mail that had built up*".